# Is there way to open a url without creating a new tab in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, single-sign-on

I am creating SSO functionaility and one of the steps is after you create a JWT token url , you redirect to this new url to complete the sign in . Is it possible to redirect to this url in angularjs or nodejs WITHOUT redirecting or creating a new tab?

Edit: How is this a duplicate? I am not asking how to save the JWT I am asking how to redirect without physically redirecting....like what.

Comment: .... *redirect* to the url... without... *redirecting*... ?

Comment: Create an hidden iframe?

Comment: redirect in the background without redirecting, yes.

Comment: are you talking about html iframes? But yeah the problem is I want to do this SSO on button click and want to user to stay on the current page and adding a new tab is a popup which popup blockers will flag.

Comment: You can add an html iframe on the button click and load the correct url to "redirect in the background".

Comment: I think you are right so please put this as the answer. Thanks :). And some people are very quick on the duplicate button.